# React Native find and disable all components on screen of certain type

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm thinking the way to do this would be to search for all components of a certain type (TouchableOpacity, Button, etc) and adding a disabled prop to them. Something like document.getElementsByName().

Using RN >0.60 and functional components.

I don't want to disable the entire screen as I still want the user to be able to scroll lists and such.

I want to be able to do this from a child component that I will be adding to lots of different screens so going through and adding refs to hundreds of components that I may want to disable or something like that won't work I think.

To be less ambiguous, I'm trying to disable user input to anything on the screen that sends an api request if there's no internet connection.

Comment: I am having the same situation myself, I am thinking of extending the TextInput and TouchableOpacity to my own custom one which pulls information a React Context that would globally disable or enable them.  Seems a bit of overengineering though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use state or hooks to solve this:

1. assign a state to detect the internet connection:

   if there is internet connection ->  connection = true;

   if there is no connection ->  coonection = false;
2. in ur component in style prop detect the state:

   style={this.state.connection?{display:none;}:{display:block}}

i hope this will help you

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid, having to add style={this.state.connection?{display:none;} to every single component all through my entire app, currently hundreds.